# Azure AD App Registration fail to create Service Principals when creating using another Service Principal via az cli

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-service-principal

I created an Azure DevOps Service Connection that uses an App Registration / SPN - master-app which has the following API Permissions (Graph - Application (Not Delegated) - Admin Consent Yes):

```
    Application.ReadWrite.All
    Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy
    Directory.ReadWrite.All
```

When I used the following command `az ad app create --display-name mynewapp`, it created mynewapp along with SPN associated with it. However, since 2 days the same command is creating the mynewapp but without the SPN.

Why has it stopped creating associated SPN now? It worked with the same ServiceConnection or directly az cli. I tried to do az account clear / az logout and re-login using Master-APP ClientID and SecretID but it still can't create the associated SPN!

Any idea what must have gone wrong?

I read somewhere that SPNs can only create App Regs without SPNs but if that is true, how did the pipeline create App Reg with SPN previously?

Comment: The command 'az ad app create' only creates the App Registration. To create the Service Principal, use the command 'az ad sp create-for-rbac'. Refer to the [Ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-sp-tutorial-1?tabs=bash#create-a-service-principal) for more details. If you create the App Registration from the portal, then the Service Principal will also be created automatically.

Comment: Yes, eventually I did the same - created the App Reg and then with the same name created SPN. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **`@VenkatV`** has clarified, unlike manually creating an App registration on Azure Portal, the command '**`az ad app create --display-name {appName}`**' just creates a confidential client application registration, and it does not automatically create a service principal for the new client application together.

After executing the '**`az ad app create`**' command, you also need to execute the command '**`az ad sp create --id {clientId}`**' to create a service principal for the client application. At this time, we can consider the application registration process is completed.

---

If just executing the '**`az ad app create`**' command, can see the client application generated on the Azure Portal UI. However, if running the command '**`az ad sp show --id {clientId}`**', it could return the error like as below.

> **`Resource '{clientId}' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.`**

After using '**`az ad sp create`**' command, the '**`az ad sp show`**' command can successfully return the right information.

---

For more details, you can see reference the documentation "[**Register a client application using CLI and REST API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/register-application-cli-rest)".

Comment: @BuggyB, Is there any update from you?